# How do I delete a view?

Tags: mongodb, view

I have created a view using the command below in mongoSH:

```
db.createView('tasksWithIsDelayed','tasks',[{ $project : {"isDelayed": false}}])
```

how do I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a view, use the [db.collection.drop()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/#mongodb-method-db.collection.drop) method on the view.

```
db.tasksWithIsDelayed.drop()
```

> Removes a collection or view from the database. The method also removes any indexes associated with the dropped collection. The method provides a wrapper around the drop command.

Comment: ahh it is a new collection that should thus be referenced. Well, gotta start somewhere.